# Как изменить url через htaccess?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

У меня есть страница:

```
site.ru/application/buy.php?id_product=book
```

хочу, чтобы было:

```
site.ru/order/book/
```

как это сделать?

Comment: то есть, если написать в браузере `site.ru/order/book/`, то должен быть вызван `buy.php`?

Comment: Возможно `RewriteEngine on <br/> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_product=([^=&]+) [NC] <br/> RewriteRule ^.*$  http://site.ru/order/%1? [NC,L,R=301]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^order/book/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ application/buy.php?id_product=$1
```

Comment: Может вместо book нужно сделать первую группу?

Comment: @ReinRaus Да например `site.ru/order/book/12345` на `site.ru/application/buy.php?id_product=12345`

Comment: Просто мне на основе входных данных кажется, что должно быть так:  `RewriteRule ^order/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ application/buy.php?id_product=$1`

Comment: Вроде да но не знаю скажет `zoinx2012`!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^order/book/$ /application/buy.php?id_product=book
```